# how to match python list and integer to solidity smart contract uint256[] and uint256. web3.py

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, web3.py

```
web3.exceptions.ValidationError:
Could not identify the intended function with name `storeSurvey`, positional argument(s) of type `(<class 'int'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'numpy.ndarray'>)` and keyword argument(s) of type `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `storeSurvey`: ['storeSurvey(uint256,uint256[],uint256[])']
Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types.
```

i am trying to call a transaction with arguments of type((uint256,uint256[],uint256[])) and i am passing aruguments of types(int ,list, numpy.ndarray) ,but it shows argument error.how can i solve it?

smart contract part

```
function storeSurvey(uint _sNo, uint[] memory _response, uint[] memory _diseasesPredicted) public{
  surveyCount++;
  survey[surveyCount] = Survey(surveyCount,_sNo, _response, _diseasesPredicted, msg.sender);
  // survey[surveyCount] = surv;
  bool snr = seniorRegistered[msg.sender];
  // bool pers = peopleRegistered[msg.sender];
  if(snr)
  {
    senior[msg.sender].surveys.push(surveyCount);
  }
  else{
    people[msg.sender].surveys.push(surveyCount);
  }

  emit surveyStored(surveyCount,_sNo,_response,_diseasesPredicted,msg.sender);
}
```

python

```
.
.
.

contract = web3.eth.contract(address=deployed_contract_address, abi=contract_abi)
.
.
.
@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST','GET'])
def predict():


    if request.method == 'POST':
        usersym=request.form.getlist('symptom')
        print(usersym)
        for i in range(0, len(usersym)):
            usersym[i] = int(usersym[i]) 
        symp=[]
        for i in range(132):
            symp.append(0)
        for x in usersym:
            symp[x]=1
        print(symp)
        final=[np.array(symp)]
        prediction=model.predict_proba(final)
        p=prediction.tolist()
        tx_hash = contract.functions.storeSurvey(1,symp, p).transact({'from': account1})
        tx_receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: Well, you should obviously convert `numpy.ndarray` to `list`, to begin with. Then, each one of the lists passed to the function must contain only integers.

Comment: thank you @goodvibration for your response. the list contains 0's and 1's only.

Comment: So did this work for you or not (converting `numpy.ndarray` to `list`)?

Comment: its a list now,but argument mismatch still persist.

Comment: Can you please post your contract code and python code (only the relevant part of each one of them, as well as your input values?

Comment: What is the value of `p`?

Comment: a list of 1's and 0's

Comment: That's the value of `symp`. Please run `print(type(p))`and `print([type(k) for k in p])`, and make sure that it is indeed a list of integers.

Comment: p was returning a 2D array. thank you for pointing that out.The transaction is working now